# Why does my TOTP algorithm sometimes generate the wrong OTP and other times the correct one?

Tags: python, base64, passwords, hmac, totp

I created a TOTP algorithm and provided a key from a site. When I entered that key into various sites to check if they all produce the same OTP, I found that they do. However, my algorithm sometimes generates the correct OTP and other times produces the wrong OTP. Why is this happening?

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import struct
import time
import base64

def generate_totp(secret, time_step=30, digits=6, current_time=None):
    if current_time is None:
        current_time = int(time.time())
        print("is NONE waalaa --- ",current_time)
    print(current_time)
    current_time //= time_step
    time_bytes = struct.pack('>Q', current_time)

    secret = base64.b32decode(secret, casefold=True)
    hmac_result = hmac.new(secret, time_bytes, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    offset = hmac_result[-1] & 0xF
    truncated_hash = hmac_result[offset : offset + 4]

    otp = struct.unpack('>I', truncated_hash)[0]

    otp = otp % (10 ** digits)

    otp_str = str(otp).zfill(digits)

    return otp_str, current_time

def get_time_until_next_step(time_step=30):
    current_time = int(time.time())
    print("This is the current time", current_time)
    return time_step - (current_time % time_step)

# Example Usage:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    secret_key = "2FASTEST"

    while True:
        wait_time = get_time_until_next_step()
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        current_totp, current_time = generate_totp(secret_key, current_time=int(time.time()))
        print(f"Generated TOTP: {current_totp}")
```

How to correct it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first bit of truncated hash must be 0, your code is resulting correct when the first bit is a 0, and incorrect when first bit is 1, so you must do **and** operation of truncated hash with 01111111...(32-bits)

```
otp = struct.unpack('>I', truncated_hash)[0]

otp = otp & 0x7fffffff   

otp = otp % (10 ** digits)
otp_str = str(otp).zfill(digits)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).